# Countdown timer with seconds exceeding 60 seconds

Tags: java, thread-sleep

So I tried making a simple code that acts as a countdown timer. The user would put 2 digits in the terminal, the minute and second values accordingly. Here's the code:

```
public class CountdownMins
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {

        int min = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int sec = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        for(int i=min;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=sec;j>=0;j--)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(i +" minutes" + " " + j + " seconds");
            }

                sec=60;


        }
    }

}
```

What I was wondering was what can I do if the user inputs a number greater than 60 on the 2nd input. Like if they put 120 it would convert it into 2 minutes instead or when they input 90 it would convert it into 1 minute and 30 seconds and add them accordingly to the minute value inserted

Comment: Convert the minutes to seconds, add the seconds and count down from there.  The print out can convert it back to minutes and seconds

Comment: Or you can just write your code as `if (sec > 60) { sec = 60; }`. It's your implementation, so you decide.

Comment: Also remember that `sleep` is the minimum time that it will sleep, so if you want any accuracy you should incorporate `System.currentTimeMillis()` see @Elliott answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) to perform most of the heavy lifting, convert everything to milliseconds and perform your calculations. Something like,

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long total = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min) + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(sec);
long remain;
while ((remain = start + total - System.currentTimeMillis()) > 0) {
    try {
        long reMin = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(remain);
        long reSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                .toSeconds(remain - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(reMin));
        System.out.printf("%d minutes, %d seconds%n", reMin, reSec);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could divide sec by 60 and add the dividend to minutes and put the rest as sec.

```
min += sec / 60;
sec = sec % 60;
```

if you want to be safe with negatives also add:

```
if(sec < 0){sec += 60;}
```